# Vector geometry involving parallel vectors

Tags: vectors

I found this question on vector geometry in an IGCSE text. I got these solutions for the following vectors: $\vec {BP}=\mathbf a-\mathbf b$, $\vec {AB}=\mathbf b-3\mathbf a$, $\vec {MB}=\frac 12(\mathbf b-3\mathbf a)$. Then for $\vec {MX}$ I got this really long and complicated expression in terms of $\mathbf a$, $\mathbf b$ and $\mathit k$:
$$\vec {MX}=\frac 12(\mathbf b-3\mathbf a)+\mathit k(\mathbf a-\mathbf b)=\left(\mathit k-\frac 32\right)\mathbf a+\left(\frac 12-\mathit k\right)\mathbf b$$

As I understand, if $\vec {MX}$ is parallel to $\vec {BO}$, $\vec {MX}$ would be something times $\vec {BO}$. But how do you use that result to find the value of $\mathit k$?[image: Snapshot of the text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are parallel if there is a scalar $c$, so $\mathbf u =c\mathbf v$. So if $\vec{MX}$ is parallel to $\vec{OB}$, then there should be $c$:
$$
\left(k-\frac32\right)\mathbf a+\left(\frac12-k\right)\mathbf b=c\mathbf b
$$

But since $\mathbf a$ isn't parallel to $\mathbf b$, it can't be true until $k-3/2=0$.

Comment: So if $\vec {MX}$ is parallel to $\vec {OB}$, $\vec {MX}=\mathit c\vec {OB}$ where $\mathit c$ is a scalar. But $\vec {OB}=\mathbf b$ and $\vec {MX}=\left (\mathit k-\frac 32 \right)\mathbf a+\left(\frac 12-\mathit k\right)\mathbf b$. Unless $\mathbf a$ is parallel to $\mathbf b$, $\vec {MX}$ is parallel to $\vec {OB}$ iff $\mathit k=\frac 32$. Therefore it must be that $\mathit k=\frac 32$ if $\vec {MX}$ is parallel to $\vec {OB}$. Is that how the reasoning go?

Comment: Can we reason like that though?

Comment: Yes, that is the right reasoning